# prove that $\int_{A \cup B} f \, dm + \int_{A \cap B} f \, dm =\int_{B} f \, dm+ \int_{A } f \, dm$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $f$ be a non-negative measurable function. Prove that for $A$ and $B$ measurable subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, the following holds:
$$
\int_{A \cup B} f \, dm + \int_{A \cap B} f \, dm =\int_{B} f \, dm+ \int_{A } f \, dm
$$
my attempt
As $A$ and $B$ are not disjoint, my idea was to use properties of measurable functions, that is, if $A$ is a subset of $B$, then the $\int_A f \, dm$  $\leq$  $\int_B f \, dm$. In this case, $A$ is a subset of $A \cup B$ and $B$ is a subset of $A \cup B$, so the $\int_A f \, dm$  $\leq$  $\int_{A \cup B} f \, dm$, and $\int_B f \, dm$  $\leq$  $\int_{A \cup B} f \, dm$ so

$$\int_A f \, dm  + \int_B f \, dm  \leq  2\int_{A \cup B} f \, dm$$

and $A\cap B$ is a subset of $A$, $A\cap B$ is a subset of $B$ so

$$2\int_{A \cap B} f \, dm \leq  \int_A f \, dm  + \int_B f \, dm$$

I don't see a way to handle this, and I'm not sure if I'm doing it right. Any help is welcome

Comment: The Lebesgue integral is additive on disjoint measurable sets. Decompose the sets on both sides into disjoint sets, and deduce that both expressions are equal.

Comment: Considering $f \equiv 1$ might be a helpful to get an intuition.